# How to upload image file into the SharePoint picture library using ECMA Script

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, javascript

I require code to upload image  file to sharepoint picture library using javascript or ecma script. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per few Articles I came across, its not possible to do so with only JavaScript. Here is one thread
[Click Here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/34cc5d22-f47b-4ac4-9057-bbcc9f9baadd/ecma-script-for-uploading-image-to-sharepoint-2010-document-library?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)